# Using Process.Start to open a URL with username, password, domain

Tags: vb.net

When opening a URL with the default browser, the following works fine:

```
Process.Start(@"https://www.reddit.com/r/zeronet")
```

This works the same as the 'start' command on the console. However, in [the documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/53ezey2s(v=vs.110).aspx), this argument is meant to be a filename or application.

Some old code I've seen opens up URLs by opening Internet Explorer with the URL as an argument, but it uses a ProcessStart object:

```
Dim tempProcessObj As New ProcessObject(<location of IE on the machine>)
tempProcessObj.Domain = "Domain"
tempProcessObj.UserName = "UserName"
tempProcessObj.Password = new SecureString();
tempProcessObj.Arguments = "https://www.reddit.com/r/zeronet"

Process.Start(tempProcessObj)
```

This throws an exception, "The system cannot find the file specified". This is probably because the fileName argument *meant* to be a file or executable location.

So, based on this, I ask:

1. If urls are supported by Process.Start(String), then why not in Process.Start(ProcessStartInfo)?
2. When launching a URL, not an executable, is a UserName/Password/Domain even relevant? (ie is there a case that it would need this?)
3. If this is the 'wrong' way to launch a URL in the default browser, what is the right way?

Answer (score 1):

Based on your description it looks like the Process Start object is unable to find the IE executable at the location you have specified.

When you try to navigate to a website in a browser based on the web server's authentication settings, the browser can ask you user credentials but in your case it actually does not make any sense to provide the creds to the web site url.

Typically, you would launch a web site by passing the URL to the Process.Start,as you have shown in your first code snippet. This would automatically ensure that the web site is opened in your machine's default browser.